# Qt/C++: How to deploy Qt application for windows

Tags: c++, qt

I tried to follow this [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) to deploy application for Windows, but I don't have the file `configure` and I am unable to run the command.

Any help ?

Comment: I have no experience, but I think your title should read "Qt"? Additionally, have you performed the right steps outlined [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-support.html) to install QT support on Windows?

Comment: Yes, the Qt works fine no problem at all

Answer (score 3):

Skip the `configure` step. What you need is the [windeployqt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html#the-windows-deployment-tool) utility.
Afterwards you may need to remove some libraries your project doesn't use. For my projects, `windeployqt` insists to deploy a huge `openglsw.dll` (or something like that), even though I don't need it.

I also recommend simply copying the MSVC libraries into your distribution rather than installing from the supplied installer package. Just make sure you got all of them, the right version and for the right architecture.

If you use the Qt Network module, you may want to also deploy the [OpenSSL binaries](https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/) - you'll need them if you want to access HTTPS resources.

And my last advice - use [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) for installer. It is well documented, very well written, very easy to use and produces no junk.

P. S. You could use one of my open source projects for reference, I have a [script](https://github.com/VioletGiraffe/file-commander/tree/master/installer/windows) to copy all the necessary files into one folder and pack it into an installer using Inno Setup. I try to keep the scripts as simple and short as possible, no junk there.

Comment: Yes, assuming he is using QT 5.1 or newer, this is definitely the best choice. For earlier versions however, you have to collect the necessary libraries manually, as windeployqt either does not exist or happens to work incorrectly. I had to suffer from this experience with a QT 5.0 project.

Comment: @gilgamash: I was unaware of that. The first Qt version that was even remotely usable on any of my projects is 5.3, so I can't speak for older versions.

Comment: Do use the install package for the MSVC dependencies, or you are going to make a mess with other libraries (typically shell extensions) which load the same runtime from different locations (and with/without SxS). I wasted a week once trying to debug issues arising from morons distributing their own broken copy of the CRT and leaving it around in shared paths, don't be the next offender, just bundle the installer.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: I assume you are referring to installers, that blindly copy the MSVC runtime libraries to a shared location. This is the wrong approach altogether. Bundling the binaries (without using the prebuilt installer package) with the application, and having the installer copy the files into the target application's location is fine, though.

Comment: Ok, I've done the first paragraph, I many file have been created ( or should I say collected) . about the MSVC libraries, what are their extension (forgive my knowledge) ?

Comment: @MatteoItalia: obviously, don't copy MSVC libraries to shared paths, keep them beside your .exe - in a separate folder.

Comment: @IInspectable: you start your application with its own copy of the CRT (which, depending on the manifest, may not actually be the one being loaded at all). Then you open the file dialog, which loads up a ton of shell extensions, many of which refer to the same CRT version. Which dll are they provided with? The system one? Yours that is already loaded in the process? Don't go down this road. Either you link statically (but then you have to link statically against Qt too), or you have to make sure that every module which refers to some CRT version actually refers to the same file.

Comment: (Also, I don't really see how bundling the installer and running it in silent mode as a pre-install step is such a burden compared to copying manually the CRT dlls)

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Shell extensions are implemented as COM objects. COM objects use the COM memory allocator. Passing COM objects across DLL boundaries is therefore not an issue. You are referring to transferring CRT resources across DLL boundaries (which is a potential issue).

Comment: @MatteoItalia: silent or not, that installer is way too slow and too fat for my liking.

Comment: In all fairness, though, the *"fatness"* of the MSVC CRT install package is a fraction of the size of the Qt libraries required for even the most simplistic *"Hello, World!"* application.

Comment: @IInspectable: I wouldn't say so: the MSVC package weighs ~6MB, if memory serves, and my whole QtCore + QtGui project results in a 12 MB installer (_compressed_) - including the MSVC .dlls that I included into the installer as plain files..